# How to implement the itunes store RSS into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss, itunes

I am trying to incorporate the RSS feed from the itunes store into my wordpress site. Here is the link to the itunes store rss: http://itunes.apple.com/rss

Ultimately, my goal is to make a site that is similar to http://iphoneapplicationlist.com/apps/

If there is another way to have a feed that supplies apps from the app store, I would be open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As easy as Google's RSS API http://code.google.com/apis/feed/  or use a plugin like  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available that displays App Store charts (search for Appstore top charts) - this is a side-bar widget but can be featured in your main content if you download another plugin that add widgets to pages.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided a link to information about the plugin.